# Signature with keystore java

Tags: java, pdf, x509certificate, keystore, sign

I create a certificate with keytool:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias sara -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass
password -keystore "\Sviluppo\JavaKeyStore\keystore.jks" -storepass
12345678 -validity 360 -dname "cn=Sara, ou=***, o=***, l=Padova,
s=Italia, c=IT"
```

Then i want to sign a pdf with this certificate, i use Itextpdf to sign a pdf.
First I load private key and certificate from keystore:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
File fileKeyStore = new File(pathKeyStore);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileKeyStore);
keyStore.load(fis, "12345678".toCharArray());
final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("sara", "password".toCharArray());
final Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(certID);
```

then I open document for calculate hash to sign:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(pdfInputPath), null);
OutputStream pdfOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfOutputPath);

PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, pdfOutputStream, '\0', tempPathFile, true)
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
dic.setDate(dateNow);
sap.setCryptoDictionary(dic);
sap.setCrypto(privateKey, keyStore.getCertificateChain("sara"), null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);

HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, (int) (6144 * 2 + 2));
sap.preClose(exc);
```

then calculate hash of sap.getRangeStream(), load certificate from keystore:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sap.getRangeStream());
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(bis, digest);
byte[] buff = new byte[512];
while (dis.read(buff) != -1) {
  ;
}
dis.close();
dis = null;
byte[] hashToSign= digest.digest();
bis.close();
```

I sign with certificate from keystore:

```
java.security.Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(hashToSign);
byte[] hashSigned = signature.sign();
```

at the end close pdf:

```
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[6144];
System.arraycopy(hashSigned, 0, paddedSig, 0, hashSigned.length);
PdfDictionary pdfDictionary = new PdfDictionary();
pdfDictionary.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));
sap.close(pdfDictionary);
```

But the pdf signed is invalid: "**There are errors in the formatting or information contained in this signature**"

What's the problem, the certificare or signature?
Thanks for help
Sara

Comment: Why are you building directly the hash to sign and embedding the digital signature instead of using itext support? there are many possible points of failure. For example you are not including the certification chain into pdf

Comment: The code to sign pdf work properly if i call an external server (example Aruba CA) and i send only hash. But if i generate certificate with keytool, the pdf is incorrectly. I have also add certificate chain:  
sap.setCrypto((PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("sara", "password".toCharArray()), keyStore.getCertificate("sara").getCertificateChain(), null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);  
but there is same problem.

Comment: Do not include code in comments, it is difficult to read. Just edit your own question. You should include all the related code, including how you calculate `hashToSign`. But if your code works with an external CA, and not with a selfsigned certificate, then the issue is probably there. Check that your certificate is correctly generated

Comment: Sorry, I have edit my question and add code to calculate hashToSign. I am trying to generate a valid certificate but I have not succeded.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF signed with your code for analysis.

Comment: That being said, you on the one hand use `SELF_SIGNED` in your `sap.setCrypto` which indicates that you want to create a `adbe.x509.rsa_sha1` **SubFilter** signature, and on the other hand set the **SubFilter** to `adbe.pkcs7.detached` in your `PdfSignature` constructor. This does not match at all, `adbe.x509.rsa_sha1` uses naked PKCS1 signature values while `adbe.pkcs7.detached` uses a CMS signature container. Which of these do you want? As an aside, both choices are relics of bygone times...

Comment: The solution of my problem is here (par. Listing 12.21 Signatures.java): http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/digital-signatures-ocsp-and-timestamping-part-2-itext-5/       Thanks for help, Sara

Comment: And how generate a certificate is here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggezy/index.html

Comment: I just saw that you sent an example PDF via email. (I only use that address for mailing list management and, therefore, only seldom poll it.) This example essentially only proofs what I indicated in my comment above: You put a naked PKCS1 signature value where a full-fledged CMS signature container is expected. Thus, I'll make my comment an answer.Concerning the link you shared with *"The solution of my problem is here"*: That link contains a rip-off copy of a book published by the original iText author and as such might no be generally well-received.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the "There are errors in the formatting or information contained in this signature" validation failure message is that your code puts a naked PKCS1 signature value where a full-fledged CMS signature container is expected:

You on the one hand use `SELF_SIGNED` in your `sap.setCrypto` which indicates that you want to create an ***adbe.x509.rsa_sha1* SubFilter** signature, and on the other hand set the **SubFilter** to ***adbe.pkcs7.detached*** in your `PdfSignature` constructor.

This does not match at all, ***adbe.x509.rsa_sha1*** uses naked PKCS1 signature values while ***adbe.pkcs7.detached*** uses CMS signature containers.

This should answer your question "What's the problem, the certificare or signature?"...

---

According to a comment you meanwhile found a solution in a copy of iText in Action, 2nd Edition.

Please be aware, though, that the iText signing API meanwhile has been substantially extended. If you are working with iText 5.5.x, you should download and read [Digital Signatures for PDF Documents](https://developers.itextpdf.com/books#digsig), a white paper by Bruno Lowagie (iText Software).

While the code from *iText in Action, 2nd Edition*, still focused on signatures according to ISO 32000-1:2008 (SOTA at the time of its publishing but not anymore), *Digital Signatures for PDF Documents* focuses on signatures according to PAdES which meanwhile have been included in ISO 32000-2:2017.